# Why is Agricola named as such?

Tags: game-design, agricola

[Agricola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agricola_(board_game)) is a farming game that shares a name with a (mildly) famous [Roman general](http://www.bbc.co.uk/history/historic_figures/agricola.shtml). They have the same pronunciation, i.e. the game is not pronounced as agri-cola.

Given that Agricola the general isn't super famous, especially not as a farmer, then why does the game share his name?

Comment: "i.e. the game is not pronounced as agri-cola." - wait, then how *is* it pronounced?

Comment: /aˈɡri.ko.la/, [aˈɡrɪ.kɔ.ɫa]

Answer (score 74, accepted):

“Agricola” is the Latin word for “farmer” ([dictionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/agricola#Latin)).

It is derived from “ager” (“field”) and “-cola” (“-tiller”, “-cultivator”). [“Agriculture”](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/agriculture#English) shares the same root, and so does [“acre”](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/acre#English) (albeit indirectly).

That a Roman general had it as his last name is unrelated.

Comment: I think my question came about by having an interest in Roman history but no knowledge of Latin :-)

Comment: It's probably not totally unrelated - I'll bet that the general was a farmer or was descended from farmers.

Comment: @ArcanistLupus Probably not unrelated, yeah. One of the Roman naming conventions was occupational names, like the English last names Smith, Cooper, Taylor, etc.

Comment: @ArcanistLupus: OK, but the general is unrelated to the game.

Comment: @Zombie_Gamer Never mind. History is written by the winning generals, not the farmers.

Comment: FWIW, "Agricola" is also a word in Spanish (which is derived from Latin), and is an adjective that basically means "pertaining to Agriculture"

Comment: @ArcanistLupus Well, yes. Probably almost every Roman was.